# What will be the direction of the force required on the ball to move the ball up the stairs?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, torque, moment

Is this diagram correct?
The point of force A is at the farthest distance from the fixed centre O ,so the moment arm CD is greater and therefore,maximum torque would be produced.Is my concept correct?So,is the required direction of force AB?[image]

Comment: The diagram is OK.  The torque about O produced by the force A should exceed the torque by gravity about that same point.

Comment: Your stated direction for force "A" will allow the minimum amount of force required to roll the ball up the stair.  However, note that many other force application directions can also roll the ball up the stair, but will require more force than the minimum.

Answer (score -2):

$ W = \int (mah + max) d \theta  $

using $ h = r\sin(\theta) $ and $ x = r \cos(\theta) $

get $ W =  \int ma(r\sin(\theta)) + ma(r \cos(\theta)) d \theta $

$ W = -ma r\cos(\theta) + ma r\sin(\theta) $

if we use $ a = v^{2}/r $

get

$ W = -mv^{2} \cos(\theta) + mv^{2} \sin(\theta) $

$ W = mv^{2} (\sin(\theta) - \cos(\theta)) $